# How do sort custom object in an array in swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

```
class MyClass {
    var name: String?
    var address: String?

    init(name: String, address: String){
        self.name = name
        self.address = address
    }
}

let array = [MyClass(name: "John", address: "USA"), MyClass(name: "Smith", address: "UK"),MyClass(name: "Paul", address: "AUS"), MyClass(name: "Peter", address: "RSA")]
```

> Now how can sort the array by name of MyClass object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let sortedArray = array.sort { $0.name < $1.name }
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

```
array.sortInPlace { $0.name < $1.name }
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct way to implement this is to ensure your custom class conforms to the Comparable protocol and provides the implementations < and == operators. This will enable you to provide custom comparison and make it extensible.

Come up with an extension-

```
extension MyClass:Comparable{};


func ==(x: MyClass, y: MyClass) -> Bool {
    return x.name == y.name  //Add any additional conditions if needed
 } 

func <(x: MyClass, y: MyClass) -> Bool { 
   return x.name < y.name  //You can add any other conditions as well if applicable.
}
```

Now you can sort your array of object of this custom class like

```
let sorted = array.sort(<)
```